# Using .replaceWith to remove <p> tags but keep content inside tags?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a table cell containing content that's wrapped in `<p>` tags:

```
<td class=" address"><p>
    Content goes here
</p></td>
```

I want the `<p>` tags removed so it looks like this:

```
<td class=" address">
    Content goes here
</td>
```

I tried the following jQuery, but it didn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
$('.address p').replaceWith('');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.address p').contents().unwrap();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/34/ (uses `div` instead of `td` but the concept should be the same)

*Explanation:*

[`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) gets elements inside the paragraph tag (including text elements), and then calls [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap) on those text elements, removing the parent `p` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("td.address > p").contents().unwrap();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.address p').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YeMbC/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would use [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method

```
$('p').contents().unwrap();
```

Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

Comment: Sorry negative is happened due to accidental click.